# Scala: sort comparing with adjacent elements

Tags: scala, list, sorting, functional-programming

Assuming I have the following Scala classes:

```
Human(id: String, task: Task)

Task(id: String, time: Duration)
```

And having a `List[(Human, Task)]` with the following elements:

```
("H2", Task("T3", 5 minute))

("H3", Task("T1", 10 minute))

("H1", Task("T1", 10 minute))

("H1", Task("T2",  5 minute))
```

Now I want to functionally check if close elements have the same duration, and if so, order them by the human id.

In this case, the final list would have the elements sorted like so:

```
("H2", Task("T3", 5 minute))

("H1", Task("T1", 10 minute))

("H3", Task("T1", 10 minute))

("H1", Task("T2",  5 minute))
```

I tried to use sortBy to do so, but the way I'm doing, the final list will be fully ordered by the Human ID, not comparing the times.

Does anyone have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: And what is "the way you are doing it"?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit confused. You say you have a `List` of `(Human,Task)` tuples, but then you describe a collection of `(String,Task)` tuples.

Here's a way to sort a `List[Human]` according to the rules you've described.

```
def sortHumans(hs: List[Human]): List[Human] =
  if (hs.isEmpty) Nil
  else {
    val target = hs.head.task.time
    hs.takeWhile(_.task.time == target).sortBy(_.id) ++
      sortHumans(hs.dropWhile(_.task.time == target))
  }
```